# Function Pointer handler

Tags: c

I am trying to write function for Initialise system while inserting a function pointer for System triggered handling with System index and the value
So How can I access the variables `index` and `val` in `System_Init` function

```
typedef void (*System_Handler)(unsigned int short indx, char val);

void System_Init(Switch_Handler sw_hdl)
{
  unsigned short int test; 
  test = indx;
  /* Need to access variables indx and val  Here . How can we do ?*/
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: In `System_Init` I do not see anything of `System_Handler`. So what do you mean?

Comment: Please read this: [ask]  and show a [mcve]

Comment: Is the System_Init argument supposed to be a System_Handler not a Switch_Handler? (And a pointer type?) And if you're passing in a function pointer then I'm not sure what you're trying to do in accessing its arguments: the point is you can call the pointer, you're not implementing the function parameter there.

Answer (score 3):

Function pointers don't come bundled with a set of function arguments. 
You have to provide the arguments separately, usually by passing them alongside with the function pointer:

```
typedef void (*System_Handler)(unsigned int short indx, char val);

void System_Init(System_Handler sw_hdl, unsigned short indx, char val)
{
  unsigned short int test; 
  test = indx;
  //...
  sw_hdl(indx,val);
}
```